# Windows explorer context menu for a file extension gives error

Tags: windows, contextmenu, regedit

I am new on WinExplorer context menu and I am trying to make a simple application for ".png" extension.

So I opened a path to registry as:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pngfile\shell\test\command`

and entered the default value as:

`my_applications_exe_path %1`

It shows up in the right click context menu for PNG files but when I click it, it gives an error:

`Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item`

And my application is so simple.It writes the filename sent:

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
   if(args.Length > 0)
      Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
}
```

I can't understand why this is happening. So how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the full path instead.

Comment: What do you mean fullpath?